# Is there any way to generate multiple sequence diagrams at once in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml, documentation-generation, sequence-diagram

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate to generate sequence diagrams for my application by right clicking on method names and selected "Generate sequence diagram...". Is there any way to generate multiple sequence diagrams at once? e.g. being able to generate all sequence diagrams for a class would be really useful. (I'm documenting a project for university and generating a sequence diagram for all my methods and copy pasting to MS Word is killing me).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, but if you want to submit that as a feature suggestion, please do at [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/).